# Error Export from SQLite Database. Python

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I have a database with historical stock closing data for all the stocks in the S&P500.
In the DB there is a table for each ticker.
I couldn't figure out how to do the SQL command to export the close information for all the tables so I used the command "'SELECT * FROM ' + stock" to loop through each table and export information. Function codes is like this:

```
def ExportOneTickerData(db, stock):
  conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
  df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM ' + stock, conn)
  df = df.drop(['Open', 'High', 'Low'], axis=1)
  df = df.rename(columns={"Close": stock})
  df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
  #print(df)
  return df
  conn.close()
```

My loop looks like this:

```
for ticker in tickers:
    ticker_df = ExportOneTickerData(db, ticker)
    ticker_df = ticker_df[['Date',ticker]]
    ticker_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(ticker_df['Date']) # to set Date column from string to datetime format
    ticker_df.set_index('Date', inplace=True) # set Date column as Index
    print(ticker_df)
    merged_df = pd.merge_asof(merged_df.sort_values('Date'), ticker_df.sort_values('Date'), on='Date')
    print(merged_df)
    time.sleep(1) # sleep 1 second for each ticker to give db time
```

It would work successfully for 10 tickers and then I would get this error:
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM ALL': near "ALL": syntax error

Full error is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pavel\Anaconda3\envs\HelperFiles\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1697, in execute
    cur.execute(*args, **kwargs)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "ALL": syntax error
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Pavel/Dropbox/Toolkit/Python/OHLC_DatabaseScrape/main.py", line 36, in <module>
    ticker_df = ExportOneTickerData(db, ticker)
  File "C:\Users\Pavel\Dropbox\Toolkit\Python\OHLC_DatabaseScrape\assets.py", line 132, in ExportOneTickerData
    df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM ' + stock, conn)
  File "C:\Users\Pavel\Anaconda3\envs\HelperFiles\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 383, in read_sql_query
    chunksize=chunksize,
  File "C:\Users\Pavel\Anaconda3\envs\HelperFiles\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1743, in read_query
    cursor = self.execute(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Pavel\Anaconda3\envs\HelperFiles\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1709, in execute
    raise ex from exc
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM ALL': near "ALL": syntax error
```

Very odd that it would work for approximately 10 tickers and then jam up. It should either work or not work from the beginning.

Comment: "ALL" is a [reserved word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). You will need to escape it with square brackets to use it as a table name. But i see now you have tagged sql server but your question refers to sqlite - don't add confusion by referring to different database engines.

Comment: SQLite reserved words at [link] (https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html). "ALL" is reserved, interesting that when you created this table Sqlite did not threw the error!

Comment: I thought SQL and SQLite had same commands. "ALL" is used to specify all tables. How would I get export out of all the tables otherwise?